# Very very Simple Application

Tags: android

So, I'm just starting to learn how to code Java/Android
but i've been making this real simple code, but i seem to to get stuck......

MainAcitivty.Java

```
package com.example.button;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.os.Build;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    int counter;
    Button add, sub;
    TextView display;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
            counter = 0;
            add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bAdd);
            sub = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSub);
            display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDisplay);

            add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    counter+=1;
                    display.setText("Your Total is "+ counter);
                }
            });

            sub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    counter-=1;
                    display.setText("Your Total is "+ counter);
                }
            });

        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                    false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

fragment_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.button.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Your Total is 0" 
    android:textSize="40dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/tvDisplay"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bSub"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tvDisplay"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvDisplay"
    android:hint="Subtract one"
    android:textSize="20dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bAdd"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/bSub"
    android:layout_below="@+id/bSub"
    android:hint="Add one"
    android:textSize="20dp" />

  </RelativeLayout>
```

AndoridManifest.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.button"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.button.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Error I've been getting

```
    04-04 04:15:22.332: E/AndroidRuntime(1524): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    04-04 04:15:22.332: E/AndroidRuntime(1524): Process: com.example.button, PID: 1524
    04-04 04:15:22.332: E/AndroidRuntime(1524): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity     ComponentInfo{com.example.button/com.example.button.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    04-04 04:15:22.332: E/AndroidRuntime(1524):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
    04-04 04:15:22.332: E/AndroidRuntime(1524):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
    04-04 04:15:22.332: E/AndroidRuntime(1524):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
    04-04 04:15:22.332: E/AndroidRuntime(1524):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
    04-04 04:15:22.332: E/AndroidRuntime(1524):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    04-04 04:15:22.332: E/AndroidRuntime(1524):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    04-04 04:15:22.332: E/AndroidRuntime(1524):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
    04-04 04:15:22.332: E/AndroidRuntime(1524):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    04-04 04:15:22.332: E/AndroidRuntime(1524):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    04-04 04:15:22.332: E/AndroidRuntime(1524):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
    04-04 04:15:22.332: E/AndroidRuntime(1524):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
    04-04 04:15:22.332: E/AndroidRuntime(1524):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    04-04 04:15:22.332: E/AndroidRuntime(1524): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    04-04 04:15:22.332: E/AndroidRuntime(1524):     at com.example.button.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:35)
    04-04 04:15:22.332: E/AndroidRuntime(1524):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
    04-04 04:15:22.332: E/AndroidRuntime(1524):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
    04-04 04:15:22.332: E/AndroidRuntime(1524):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
    04-04 04:15:22.332: E/AndroidRuntime(1524):     ... 11 more
```

Thank you so much for they help :D

New error i got after changing the Activity_main to Fragment

```
04-04 04:44:46.902: E/AndroidRuntime(1575): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-04 04:44:46.902: E/AndroidRuntime(1575): Process: com.example.button, PID: 1575
04-04 04:44:46.902: E/AndroidRuntime(1575): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.button/com.example.button.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f05003c (com.example.button:id/container) for fragment PlaceholderFragment{b1dcdaa0 #0 id=0x7f05003c}
04-04 04:44:46.902: E/AndroidRuntime(1575):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
04-04 04:44:46.902: E/AndroidRuntime(1575):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
04-04 04:44:46.902: E/AndroidRuntime(1575):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
04-04 04:44:46.902: E/AndroidRuntime(1575):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
04-04 04:44:46.902: E/AndroidRuntime(1575):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-04 04:44:46.902: E/AndroidRuntime(1575):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
04-04 04:44:46.902: E/AndroidRuntime(1575):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
04-04 04:44:46.902: E/AndroidRuntime(1575):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-04 04:44:46.902: E/AndroidRuntime(1575):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-04 04:44:46.902: E/AndroidRuntime(1575):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
04-04 04:44:46.902: E/AndroidRuntime(1575):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
04-04 04:44:46.902: E/AndroidRuntime(1575):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-04 04:44:46.902: E/AndroidRuntime(1575): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f05003c (com.example.button:id/container) for fragment PlaceholderFragment{b1dcdaa0 #0 id=0x7f05003c}
04-04 04:44:46.902: E/AndroidRuntime(1575):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:930)
04-04 04:44:46.902: E/AndroidRuntime(1575):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1115)
04-04 04:44:46.902: E/AndroidRuntime(1575):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
04-04 04:44:46.902: E/AndroidRuntime(1575):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1478)
04-04 04:44:46.902: E/AndroidRuntime(1575):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:570)
04-04 04:44:46.902: E/AndroidRuntime(1575):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1171)
04-04 04:44:46.902: E/AndroidRuntime(1575):     at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5241)
04-04 04:44:46.902: E/AndroidRuntime(1575):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2168)
04-04 04:44:46.902: E/AndroidRuntime(1575):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: What's your line 35 of your MainActivity.java file?

Comment: You All Buttons Views belogs to fragment_main.xml layout.

Comment: i think this question asked more than 10 time with other user like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22737319/unfortunately-application-has-stopped-android-emulator-genymotion?noredirect=1#comment34655134_22737319 with same property

Comment: @shayanpourvatan i voted to close this question as a duplicate. But if you think its the same user you can flag the question for moderator attention. Anyway this certainly seems to be a duplicate

Comment: @Raghunandan i flag for moderator attention, because i think is same user with multiple account, thanks for support

Comment: what... I just joined this website....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you ahve

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Button add is in fragment layout

```
<Button
android:id="@+id/bAdd"
```

SO your initializaton fails leading to `NullPointerException`.

You need to move the initization of your views to fragment.

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id
>   0x7f05003c (com.example.button:id/container) for fragment
>   PlaceholderFragment{b1dcdaa0 #0 id=0x7f05003c}

This clearly indicates that you do not have a ViewGroup with the id container in the layout that you set to the Activity.

coz you have

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
.add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
```

Comment: please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22737319/unfortunately-application-has-stopped-android-emulator-genymotion/22737675?noredirect=1#comment34655578_22737675 question, in that day this question with this property asked more than 10 day, i don't know why. same problem same question and same property,

Comment: @shayanpourvatan you mean to say its a duplicate?? if so vote to close the question

Comment: no i think this user sign up in this site with new user and asked this question, because i think it's impossible that all property be same each other.

Comment: @shayanpourvatan, otherway, you can post such things as question in http://meta.stackoverflow.com

Comment: @Kedarnath can you describe your suggest, why should asked there?

Comment: Because meta sites are for moderation purpose. Please checkout my meta profile and questions.

Comment: Do i need to set new Viewgroup for the container?

Comment: @user3497149 yes generally its a `Framelayout` But could be `RelativeLayout` or `LinearLayout`. You add/replace fragments to the container. So activity layout must have the same

Comment: i just created arbitrary frag id in layout. and everything works like  a charm

Comment: '<FrameLayout android:id="@+id/frag" android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />'

Comment: @user3497149 yes that is what you need. `FrameLayout` is the container that holds the fragment

Answer (score 1):

Your EditText and command Button are in fragment_main.xml file , hence change this line

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

to

```
setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);
```

Comment: it might be kinda stupid.. but was i suppose to write (button) code on the activity_main or fragment_main? what is the difference?

Comment: Its ok, you can write it in any xml file as per your needs.

Comment: still getting an error after chaging the activity_main to fragment

Comment: Is it so ?? hmm then I suggest you to move your TextView & Buttons to activity_main.xml file. And do not forget to change fragment_main to activity_main again.

Comment: i've posted the new error i've been getting

Answer (score 0):

Your `Button`, `TextView` and all other `UI` elements are not in your `activity_main` but it is in `fragment_main.xml`. So check your xml file and find id for all `UI` elements according to it.

Also you have to call

```
setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);
```

instead of

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the layout name you use when calling

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

corresponds to the file name in your project `res/layout` folder

As you mentioned above the layout seems to be `fragment_main.xml` not `activity_main*.xml`..

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're trying to do the click event handling of fragment buttons from the activity. The `bAdd` and `bSub` buttons belong to the fragment's layout, but you're trying to access them from the activity (by calling `findViewById` on the activity). These calls produce `null` since they are not in the activity's layout.

The correct way to go about this, would be to **move the handling for buttons in the fragment's layout to the fragment class**. This is how fragments are intended to be used: self-contained pieces which you can use in a parent activity. Thus, you should move most of the code from `MainActivity.onCreate` to `PlaceholderFragment.onActivityCreated`.

Alternatively, if you aren't really planning to reuse `PlaceholderFragment`, you can just get rid of it and move everything into the activity's layout. You don't *have* to use fragments for simple use cases.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure in your `activity_main` layout there is view `FrameLayout` having id `container` as below:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com....MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />
```