# Unfortunately your "APP" has stopped working

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am new to Android App development and I am having an issue with an app. I have read everything I could find on stackoverflow about the problem and checked my work against the suggestions from the other questions asked.

Thanks for the help.

[Unfortunately application has stopped android emulator genymotion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22737319/unfortunately-application-has-stopped-android-emulator-genymotion)
I am trying to run the app on a Samsung Gal 3 tab.
Below are my files

MainActivity.java

```
    package net.androidbootcamp.concerttickets;

    import java.text.DecimalFormat;

    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.Spinner;
    import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    double costPerTicket = 79.99;
    int numberOfTickets;
    double totalCost;
    String groupChoice;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final EditText tickets=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtTicket);
        final Spinner group = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.txtGroup);
        Button cost = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnCost);
        cost.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            final TextView result = ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtResult));

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                numberOfTickets = Integer.parseInt(tickets.getText().toString());
                totalCost = costPerTicket * numberOfTickets;
                DecimalFormat currency = new DecimalFormat("$###,###.##");
                groupChoice = group.getSelectedItem().toString();
                result.setText("Total Cost for" + groupChoice + "is" +     currency.format(totalCost));

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

ActivityMain.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="net.androidbootcamp.concerttickets.MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/txtTitle"
        android:textSize="48sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtTicket"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txtGroup"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/txtTickets"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:textSize="32sp" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/txtGroup"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtTicket"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:entries="@array/txtGroup"
        android:prompt="@string/prompt" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnCost"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtGroup"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/btnCost"
        android:textSize="32sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtResult"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnCost"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txtGroup"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="19dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/description"
        android:src="@drawable/concert" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="net.androidbootcamp.concerttickets"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
        <activity
            android:name="net.androidbootcamp.concerttickets.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>

LogCat
08-14 17:19:35.330: D/AndroidRuntime(20330): Shutting down VM
08-14 17:19:35.330: W/dalvikvm(20330): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41cf0e10)
08-14 17:19:35.340: E/AndroidRuntime(20330): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-14 17:19:35.340: E/AndroidRuntime(20330): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{net.androidbootcamp.concerttickets/net.androidbootcamp.concerttickets.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
08-14 17:19:35.340: E/AndroidRuntime(20330):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
08-14 17:19:35.340: E/AndroidRuntime(20330):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2295)
08-14 17:19:35.340: E/AndroidRuntime(20330):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:150)
08-14 17:19:35.340: E/AndroidRuntime(20330):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1280)
08-14 17:19:35.340: E/AndroidRuntime(20330):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-14 17:19:35.340: E/AndroidRuntime(20330):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
08-14 17:19:35.340: E/AndroidRuntime(20330):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5279)
08-14 17:19:35.340: E/AndroidRuntime(20330):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-14 17:19:35.340: E/AndroidRuntime(20330):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-14 17:19:35.340: E/AndroidRuntime(20330):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
08-14 17:19:35.340: E/AndroidRuntime(20330):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
08-14 17:19:35.340: E/AndroidRuntime(20330):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-14 17:19:35.340: E/AndroidRuntime(20330): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
08-14 17:19:35.340: E/AndroidRuntime(20330):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegate.java:110)
08-14 17:19:35.340: E/AndroidRuntime(20330):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:57)
08-14 17:19:35.340: E/AndroidRuntime(20330):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreate(ActionBarActivity.java:99)
08-14 17:19:35.340: E/AndroidRuntime(20330):    at net.androidbootcamp.concerttickets.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:26)
08-14 17:19:35.340: E/AndroidRuntime(20330):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5267)
08-14 17:19:35.340: E/AndroidRuntime(20330):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1097)
08-14 17:19:35.340: E/AndroidRuntime(20330):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2209)
08-14 17:19:35.340: E/AndroidRuntime(20330):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: How do you expect anyone to help if you dont post the crash log? We cant compile and run code in our heads, we arent THAT good.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Comment: What do you mean by issue?Please see the logcat and paste it here so that we can check what exception you are getting.

Comment: `I have read everything I could find on stackoverflow` - really?  How did you miss that you must include the crash log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The LogCat output shows that you aren't using the theme correctly. in particular, it wants you to use a compatibility theme. You can do that by altering/including a `theme` attribute for the activity in your manifest file.

If you're not actually going to use an action bar, your could also just change the parent of your activity from `ActionbarActivity` to just `Activity` like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will make the changes .

Comment: I made the changes to theme and the class change and the APP worked. Thank you again, I learned something today.

Comment: There's no need to add "thank you" comments. If someone has helped you, the best way to thank them is to accept their answer (be clicking the check-mark next to their answer) and/or up-voting (by clicking the up-arrow) if you've attained that privilege. I don't suspect you can do either on closed questions, but something to know for the future. BTW, You can also up-vote comments.